# Can I hide default points of interests in MapKit with SwiftUI like parks, restaurants etc?

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I want to use my own map annotations and I am trying to hide default annotations from Map.

I found this to remove every default annotation from the map view

```
let configuration = MKStandardMapConfiguration()
configuration.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [])
```

But how do I apply this configuration to my map view in SwiftUI?

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct MyMapView: View {
    init (){
        let configuration = MKStandardMapConfiguration()
        configuration.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [])
    }
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
            latitude: 41.59710,
            longitude: -74.14976),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(
            latitudeDelta: 0.0125,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0125)
        )
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .disabled(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From iOS 17 (Xcode 15 Beta 1) you can hide points of interest with the new `.mapStyle()` modifier: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapstyle

```
Map {
  // Annotations or Markers
}
.mapStyle(.standard(pointsOfInterest: .excludingAll))
```

It'll look like this:
[NewYork Map Without points of interests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16YMU.jpg)

You could also specify which points of interest you want to show using the `.including([])` function:

```
Map {
  // Annotations or Markers
}
.mapStyle(.hybrid(pointsOfInterest: .including([.cafe])))
```

Answer (score 1):

The SwiftUI `Map` view doesn't support this functionality. To get a map that can do this you'd need to use an `MKMapView` which is in `UIKit`. Here's an example of how to use it in SwiftUI

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapView()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .disabled(true)
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let configuration: MKStandardMapConfiguration

    private var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.59710, longitude: -74.14976)
    }

    private var coordinateSpan: MKCoordinateSpan {
        MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.0125, longitudeDelta: 0.0125)
    }

    init() {
        configuration = MKStandardMapConfiguration()
        configuration.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [])
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: coordinateSpan)
        mapView.preferredConfiguration = configuration

        return mapView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```